# Download m3u8 blob video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

The video is located on this page after clicking on the WATCH TRAILER button

https://web3.wb.com/warnermedia/movieverse

In the network tab of the browser I found several links to m3u8 playlists among which there's this link to the primary playlist

https://host-154-14-240-131.contentfabric.io/qlibs/ilibmDAMX11myzYPBC9vk2shWZYgZSc/q/hq__9Bg5pjMK35sqxXZvDBiQmec1WppnXSNbvdNWShAu5WjGE46vqpaX89FjkTgNoHrKmX1yQH1iUr/rep/playout/default/hls-clear/playlist.m3u8?resolve=true&sid=BF5B23C04336

It was missing an authorization parameter which I found in another link from the network tab. So the completed link for downloading the playlist looks like this

https://host-154-14-240-131.contentfabric.io/qlibs/ilibmDAMX11myzYPBC9vk2shWZYgZSc/q/hq__9Bg5pjMK35sqxXZvDBiQmec1WppnXSNbvdNWShAu5WjGE46vqpaX89FjkTgNoHrKmX1yQH1iUr/rep/playout/default/hls-clear/playlist.m3u8?authorization=eyJxc3BhY2VfaWQiOiJpc3BjMlJVb1JlOWVSMnYzM0hBUlFVVlNwMXJZWHp3MSJ9&resolve=true&sid=BF5B23C04336

The downloaded playlist contains several video and 1 audio streams represented as a bunch of another playlists. As their URLs in the main playlist don't have the base part, their base URL in this case should be

https://host-154-14-240-131.contentfabric.io/qlibs/ilibmDAMX11myzYPBC9vk2shWZYgZSc/q/hq__9Bg5pjMK35sqxXZvDBiQmec1WppnXSNbvdNWShAu5WjGE46vqpaX89FjkTgNoHrKmX1yQH1iUr/rep/playout/default/hls-clear/

The links to the end files inside the inner playlists are also shortened, so their base URL should be the one above + the rest part from the main playlist.
For example, the full link to the playlist with 1920x1080 stream is

https://host-154-14-240-131.contentfabric.io/qlibs/ilibmDAMX11myzYPBC9vk2shWZYgZSc/q/hq__9Bg5pjMK35sqxXZvDBiQmec1WppnXSNbvdNWShAu5WjGE46vqpaX89FjkTgNoHrKmX1yQH1iUr/rep/playout/default/hls-clear/video/videovideo_1920x1080@9500000/playlist.m3u8?authorization=eyJxc3BhY2VfaWQiOiJpc3BjMlJVb1JlOWVSMnYzM0hBUlFVVlNwMXJZWHp3MSJ9&resolve=true&sid=BF5B23C04336

I have tried to download the video through ffmpeg using the full link in this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://host-154-14-240-131.contentfabric.io/qlibs/ilibmDAMX11myzYPBC9vk2shWZYgZSc/q/hq__9Bg5pjMK35sqxXZvDBiQmec1WppnXSNbvdNWShAu5WjGE46vqpaX89FjkTgNoHrKmX1yQH1iUr/rep/playout/default/hls-clear/playlist.m3u8?authorization=eyJxc3BhY2VfaWQiOiJpc3BjMlJVb1JlOWVSMnYzM0hBUlFVVlNwMXJZWHp3MSJ9&resolve=true&sid=BF5B23C04336" -c copy -map p:0 "output.mp4"
```

But it's throwing "Creating security context failed(0x80090302) ... Unknown error occured"

How do I download the video?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835269/165358) for getting the real URL of the video.

Comment: Using your third link, JDownloader was able to extract 5 playlists in different sizes, from which I could pick which to download. I'm not really sure what you're after, but if it's a specific trailer, that's your app of choice. Presumably the other 2 movie trailers will appear when they're added to the main page. Screenshot of it playing in VLC - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kilCU.png

Comment: The answer in the other thread didn't help because I have already found the right link (the second one in my post). I have downloaded the video in the needed (1080p) quality via JDownloader, but it doesn't have any sound. So how can I download the video and the audio in a single file?

Comment: Ah, I never even noticed that. It doesn't list it at all. From such as Youtube it either gets the video + audio at several qualities, or just the audio, or the ancillaries, jpg header etc.

Comment: The audio stream is listed in the same m3u8 playlist, but it's not picked up by the program. So I hope anyone could give me the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download video + audio with [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), but you have to add an authorization :

```
yt-dlp "https://host-154-14-240-131.contentfabric.io/qlibs/ilibmDAMX11myzYPBC9vk2shWZYgZSc/q/hq__9Bg5pjMK35sqxXZvDBiQmec1WppnXSNbvdNWShAu5WjGE46vqpaX89FjkTgNoHrKmX1yQH1iUr/rep/playout/default/hls-clear/playlist.m3u8?resolve=true&sid=BF5B23C04336" --add-header "Authorization: Bearer eyJxc3BhY2VfaWQiOiJpc3BjMlJVb1JlOWVSMnYzM0hBUlFVVlNwMXJZWHp3MSJ9"
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But I got the audio and video streams separated, will need to merge them

Comment: I just tried your command again and it did the job automatically. I don't know why the merging wasn't done last time